# Does Sharing same singular vectors lead to some properties?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

What properties do a pair of matrices have if they share same ordered right singular vectors? Or for a specical case the matrices are square, what properties do they have if their ordered eigen-vectors are the same? And only consider the singular (or eigen-) vectors, it is fine if their singular (or eigen-) values are different. I know simultaneously diagonalizable and commuting family may be a view to analyse this question when the matrices are square.

Comment: The word you are looking for is spelled *singular*.

Comment: Thank you@GerryMyerson, I correct it.

Comment: You corrected it in the title, but left it in the body.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it for you.