# What is the term for two matrices sharing the same sets of singular vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, svd, singular-values, principal-component-analysis

Consider the singular value decompositions $A=U_A\Sigma_AV_A^T$ and $B=U_B\Sigma_BV_B^T$. Is there a word that describes the relation between $A$ and $B$ when they have the same left and/or right singular vectors ($U_A=U_B$ and/or $V_A=V_B$)?

If we had $\Sigma_A=\Sigma_B$ instead, then we would say that the matrices are *unitarily equivalent* [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3783583/774351)]. If we had the eigenvalue decomposition instead of the SVD, we would say the matrices are *simultaneously diagonalisable*. I am looking for a similar concise and accepted term applicable to the situation I described.

Somewhat related: [Does Sharing same singular vectors lead to some properties?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3602970/does-sharing-same-singular-vectors-lead-to-some-properties)